# Horizontal scroll in md-list

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I have a md-list, where each item in the list can be of any horizontal length:
[image]
As can be seen, long items are getting cut from the right side.
I'm using the following code:

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="element in standard_xsd_elements track by $index" ng-click="null">
                        <p style="white-space: pre;"> {{element}} </p>
</md-list-item>
```

Is there a way by which a scrollbar can appear for each of the long items (instead of those being cut off) ?

Comment: Do the list elements need to be clickable?

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm using md-list

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<p style="white-space: pre; overflow-x: scroll;"> {{element}} </p>
```